# How to handle raw JSON strings in JsonSlurper?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I'm currently trying to automate running Postman collections in our CI/CD tool.  What I noticed is that, in general, JSON strings that also contain a raw JSON string cannot be parsed.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate this.

```java
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def data = '''
{
    "request":{
        "raw": "{\n   \"Hello\": \"World\"\n}"
    }
}
'''
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
jsonData = parser.parseText(data)
println(jsonData)
```

I get the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39

The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39
line number 3
index number 7
    'request':{
....^
groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39

The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39
line number 3
index number 7
    'request':{
....^
at main.run(main.groovy:12)
```

How can I get JSONSlurper to treat the value of `raw` as a string?

Comment: you have to escape every backslash with another one  inside string value: `\\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are escaping the quotes is not correct. Please see the following.

```
import groovy.json.*

def data = '''
{
    "request":{
        "raw": "\n { \\"Hello\\": \\"World\\"} \n"
    }
}
'''
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
jsonData = parser.parseText(data)
println(jsonData)
```